# Will performance affected if using MySQL reserved keywords as field/table/db name?

Tags: mysql, performance

Will performance affected if using MySQL reserved keywords as field/table/db name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in any significant way. Not in any way at all, actually. Certainly not more than using a long string for the name, which makes parsing take nanoseconds longer.